# Join tables and accumulate values

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm a SQL rookie.

**Table A** contains information about my projects. Here we have a field for "ExpectedValue_amount" - meaning. How much were we expecting to earn/invoice on this project.

**Table B** contains our actual invoices. One project can have multiple invoices. So I want to accumulate all values on a certain project to see the difference between "ExpectedValue" and "Actual invoice value".

My query for **Table A**:

```
SELECT
  name,
  number,
  customer_name,
  expectedValue_amount,
FROM
  Projects
```

In **Table B** I have projectnumber which == number in **Table A**. But I want to see the total on a project.

```
SELECT
  projects_number,
  totalExcludingTax_amount
FROM
    Invoices
```

Desired output:
[image: Desired output]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Use JOIN to combine your tables, use SUM to sum values, use GROUP BY to group by project.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to mess a little around with joining the tables but something like this may work for you

```
SELECT
  p.name,
  p.number,
  p.customer_name,
  p.expectedValue_amount,
  SUM(i.totalExcludingTax_amount)
FROM
  Projects p JOIN Invoices i ON i.projects_number = p.number
GROUP BY p.number
```

Comment: Thanks! Only issue now is that number is INT and projects_number is STRING.

Comment: But why are they not same type? If they relate there should be a constraint on project number in the invoices table and you can't have that with different data types

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  p.name,
  p.number,
  p.customer_name,
  p.expectedValue_amount,
  SUM(i.totalExcludingTax_amount) as totalExcludingTax_amount
FROM
  Projects p 
JOIN 
  Invoices i 
  ON CAST(p.number as STRING) = i.projects_number
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
```

Comment: Thanks. "No matching signature for operator = for argument types: INT64, STRING. Supported signature: ANY = ANY at [8:119]". Probably issue since number is INT and projects_number is String?

Comment: I changed the solution to take into account the difference in column types.

Comment: You could cast both parts of your JOIN condition as the same type to avoid this type of error i.e. CAST(p.number as STRING) = CAST(i.projects_number as STRING) or CAST(p.number as INTEGER) = CAST(i.projects_number as INTEGER), you have to be sure that all values are integer though if you are going to use the second option.